# Edit ends up as second answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits

When I edited my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084120/how-to-get-ms-sql-server-to-transparently-use-a-checksum-hash-index/11084231#11084231), I ended up with two answers:

[image]

Possibly an issue in the editing code?

Comment: I have had this issue before (I just can't find my post about it at the moment)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the server logs, you did indeed request the inline editor, but then submitted the "Your Answer" form instead. And looking at the code, I can't see any way the submission route could accidentally become the wrong one.

I have to assume that you did really submit a second answer here by accident (maybe a back button was involved?), unless you can actually give reproduction steps for this; I'm unable to reproduce this or even come up with a remotely probable other explanation.

Comment: I remember doing `tab` out of the edit area then `enter` to submit.  The "Add Another Answer"  button is not visible at that point.  I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Hence my idea with the browser's back button -- if you accidentally clicked it (some mice even have an extra button for it), and the browser re-fills the "add answer" text box with what you previously had typed, it appears at first glance that you're actually editing.

Comment: I have one of those mouse buttons, let's assume that's what happened then!

Comment: @andomar we could do some kind of sanity check to make sure the exact same answer isn't posted twice, but as you can see, usually it's an edit submitted twice, so it wouldn't match anyhow.