# Edited answer, got two copies instead

Tags: bug, edits

I did a quick edit of an answer I left on this question, and now there are two answers - the original and the edit.

[PIL Image mode "P" -> "RGBA"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462548/python-pil-image-mode-p-rgba)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136539/edit-ends-up-as-second-answer

Comment: and both questions from such highly reputable users :o This can only mean one thing...

Comment: @Matt, thanks for finding that older report, it does indeed seem to be a dupe. All I can say is that I edit answers all the time, and I didn't do anything different this time.

Comment: Did you use the browser "Back" button after having created the answer, and edited the answer from that form?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I see what you're getting at - I started editing the answer that was left over in the answer window rather than hitting "Edit". I think it's unlikely because my habits are more ingrained than that, but I can't rule it out.